# scapy can't send large length packet

Tags: python, python-2.6, scapy

i use scapy

```
from scapy.all import *
send_L2sock=conf.L2socket(iface="eth0")
for send_packet in rdpcap("test.pcap"):
    send_L2sock.send(send_packet)
```

this code work well. i confirm send packet using wireshark.

but scapy can't send large packet like below:

```
GET /exp?q=jfLB9FPyAHp7oMHe.tCKVPX3wCHhZKVmBKySJoHYgtE-csHql43fyskKdzf6F7Uef-GSJ1OdDrtmUR1GomLA9yccoByMeJX9WJDnvloeMyhLKom2reGiWn9XH82ZojR9qGQwisjIDXctEmCE.SQS8-aAAYUE3kHxfq4AE3myf_Q78VsHxziE3_A7WIP3az39NxFxFePBvnPAlhte.H5WG.miDthyWva9z9NBbmCqndkckeA6evdYY7qck4Vjski53WgmuRfy.jg4nApd27WMFrkeSdA4XUvlfiqntyr5wd8AaRiv6woeUx.PwdIeZh_LYonhy7RTlJs549LJLc7M1-LNR3dQUcg_TFX_Mk6jQsaoo19lX6pZYLwpEWB3MASRcF3okwRtou-ILr8ZjF72R-pmgUcaqtQb5eYqDb3egHFSwViZ7XdGUs4CWdta-ludhSveDyXsbQjLKACC9cf2C-T99.3ccMbrLBkhXDYbIZoFdPscVdLr_oAmZMN3e7694BKoj.qEozYY5F4_ccxWNMcNcuZKBnNPgsf1MtMZWqOJnuy1s6lmFLNjjLfD_A8UmmI0&r=jfPj7L6MnFAT7vOaw3JYhRf.rirghOXccEeIuteMs85_MyLRv8cOqw7gFE8Y6Jb4fkx5eGYu4bG68IF-vzypY2uOsgjdLEahuNWYVjNKjKOIZDVs4FVTpimmM87xRLRi1a865pAp8t-ldEr_asu8uHQ1uQne5XopLjeSfJF97c39kv.mhEO7.yYdwkID4I8SRys4VcynL7xoWbSj-vCdINM21.kR_nUkhvXouJc9OFaiY3g279al418MiJGw.yMsLX6xAPwVU1exUw00&r=jfRZzkhG5VOeh3LPN46zMNYgFXkHxwhQMnhwsPO3Prf6eh6SBXxW9NgCee5Zqa_fyHWFiUDkSUmy.ZbinGnKNcAej_syDrT75pcueqUDXNBv.PWpJvo54egnrogm4LueZBdy2PaFhct2SDQa1OM9ZPaR.tcap4MndLySTVKBixJ93xSEqt2LlUup8GJtA6p5sEiyAzcf9VHD8Hl5tTYrgt1apSKFu_aB-MWxUMVWZsyPiB2HLgw8_83yb1oHibV_Xh.W3fQ7xlPRYg00&r=jfXxMnW3iZvmNlsj3_c3Bo4udASWLu_ADTFFSfJDJPtAUdMSnQCYMzC1EgkEuuWUuAs3YznlX-sU9-844Eme3ZYmj_syDrT75perH6Zbv1VsXtPvMEUXfVKGjO9Dj9a84n5B7gzL_A7IFsfjw4SlxKKgqb8iletk.zT2OvEN3r8e9Jh_flIGdMMzfzRs5.UlTikAyoNZpdcLFb79H4EymcBcEV4-14zGv3.sphU9YMl6qkjbPClgEKXn4tl29r8M9ibJ8EqE9ANotQ00&r=jfaqsn3IQmXRl4K3pCMOMN-EBhNNsPARWkN1i2xgY7nfFDnFqIzEUStIOrhPfnTDXrlqBZyf615PZ_5_ohc1kmEtd7Ra2eGnxGCk_EgxhCmuO-Vsm-A3xKIY_TcePv1AIjdZdKHR1Ych4Eic8vkC_HhP1TllHuEPd4L.tio8mPniMAAGZtGVL4qFxLASiWnS-Fe3n7-_fPmDUn-_QYgE7J5m&r=jfe4YnKJRYFENp4qDSa_92n98_dN-lTyYFj14RP-xSiWLPBXFbc3B77ODz-tx-8fNU32mbcETQjjTIMM.2G.CWoAv7ciNl9.J-ghO5P2d5A9WL5SvcHXKiO4miZCy2IXV-f9DO7XmdTA8WgjROw-u1.EgxcWiSQ2yYq-BN_oaoIdYbIW2OP1KwqWdAe5gX7VJ8aFgfuTnG8Z5cvdKzoad28GvsmMKz1CscwrFdGkr3q_HPG15c7XxwHeNwnbtLXYNWk0& HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/png, image/svg+xml, image/*;q=0.8, */*;q=0.5
Referer: http://vegadisk.com/contents/view.php?from_cate=IMG&idx=8475504
Accept-Language: ko-KR
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: keyword.daumdn.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: pref=id%3DEaG8S7X0QwiOHm715GfXtA%7Cts%3D1404084124009%7Cip%3D118.131.203.130%7Ccs%3D5729a0b58afd539b0b59f6db83533376; ae=mOqeh6nOaMrRP-hXTygYC-VNriitJP_bT-KAdhzbcnB4X2H4s8azRAJZ
```

packet length is 2475.

And packet is consist of only one packet.

why scapy can't send large length packet?

Comment: The packet is larger then your MTU, which is usually 1500 or less (depending on the layer). You have to split the data into multiple packets or use fragmentation.

Comment: @Klaus: I think you should add that as an answer.

Comment: @jsbueno Maybe. But usually I'd add some code to answers and since I was typing from my mobile I kept is short and it would be a rather low quality anwser.

Comment: Still -I think it is just the correct answer - as soon as you can, just paste it there, with maybe a link to some text explaining MTU